# Label x:Name="lblLabel1" CodeBehind use it with variable

Tags: c#, xaml, label

I have in XAML a

`Label x:Name="lblLabel1" ....................`

and want to use the name in CodeBehind with C#.

I do this: `var myLabel = lblLabel1 as Label;`

this works.
What i would like to do is to do the same with a variable, for example

```
"string myString = "lblLabel1"; var myLavel = myString as Label;"
```

This doesn't work. Do I have to solve it with Binding or is there a simpler way?
(I have several labels, thats the reason, why to to it with a variable)

Comment: What is your end goal for wanting to do this? This is almost certainly the wrong approach

Comment: the main reason is: I have 4 buttons "btnButton1" ... Clicking a button, I would check something in the code and then occasionally I would in  Label "lblLabel1" ..... change the dynamic Resource.

Comment: Your explanation is still confusing. Are you looking for something along the lines of `lblLabel1.Content = myString;`?

Comment: sorry, got a problem in answering. in codebehind the next step is: var myLabel = lblLabel1 as Label.    then     myLabel.Content = this.resource.....

Comment: sorry for asking, I found a solution !!! the appropriate code is "string myString = "lblLabel1";  var myLabel = FindName(myString) as Label; myLabel.CContent = this.resource[.....];" thanks.